# Are there any GOOD tutorials showing how to write a program using SNMP in C++?

Tags: c++, snmp

I've searched tirelessly for the past 4 days, and I've come up with nothing. I tried using net-snmp but i can't figure out how to install or use it. I'm completely lost, I don't know where to start. please help :(

Comment: Did you read the NET SNMP documentation?

Comment: So from the [INSTALL document](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/INSTALL.html) you couldn't figure out how to install it?

Comment: net-snmp is a good choice. Are you by any chance on windows? The INSTALL instructions are very unix minded. Did you read the README.win32? What steps did you do, what failed with what message?

Comment: Im on windows 7... & im going through the readme.win32 now. will update with my progress soon...

Comment: Im having issues with perl. I have perl installed, but when i try to run build.bat it tells me it cant run build.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, why not use Windows API for SNMP?

Check this out: [Windows SNMP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379001%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: im looking more for a tutorial than the API, although that does help clear up some of my confusion.